# Is there any way to keep date selected on changing Month or Year of the react-datepicker in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-datepicker

Currently, in the react-datepicker, I am using Month selector and Year selector for DOB in guest detail form.

What happening is:- 
The selected date is highlighted on the calendar, which is fine.

What I need to implement:-
When I change Month/Year on the calendar, I want to update the selected date to the same date as it was before with updated Month/Year.

Please help me with any possibility.

I am not able to find the solution for this.

The following code is what I am using for current react-datepicker:

```
    <DatePicker
        className="date-field ub-l"
        openToDate={new Date("1993/09/28")}
        selected={this.state.date}
        onSelect={this.handleChange}
        onChange={this.handleChange} //only when value has changed
        maxDate={new Date()}
        placeholderText={this.props.placeholder}
        disabledKeyboardNavigation={true}
        showMonthDropdown={true}
        showYearDropdown={true}
        name={this.props.name}
        disabledNavigation
        inputProps={{readOnly: true}}
        dropdownMode="select"
        autocomplete={false}
    />
```

If I change Month/Year is it possible to update the selected date with the updated Month/Year automatically before selecting any date?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for the `adjustDateOnChange` prop. It automatically does what you're looking for

```
<DatePicker
  selected={selectedDate}
  onChange={date => changeDate(date)}
  dropdownMode="select"
  showMonthDropdown
  showYearDropdown
  adjustDateOnChange
/>
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-wave-ujybw)

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't see this in any documentation and have been struggling with it.